# How to filter array of objects based on another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone help me know how to filter an array of objects based on another object with conditions.

Sample array

```
const arrayToFilter=  [   {
        name: 'Arlin Schistl',
        screen_name: 'aschistl1c',
        followers_count: 101,
        following_count: 657,
        location: 'Indonesia',
        verified: true,  
        },  
        {
        name: 'Henka Perren',
        screen_name: 'hperren1d',
        followers_count: 170,
        following_count: 422,
        location: 'Mexico',
        verified: true,   }, ]
```

Filter Object:

```
const conditions=[ 
    { 
        id: 'name', 
        operator: 'CONTAINS' 
        value: 'Bob', 
    },
    { 
        condition:'OR',
        id: 'followers_count', 
        operator: 'GTE' 
        value: 200, 
    }, 
    {
        condition:'AND',
        id: 'following_count', 
        operator: 'LTE' 
        value: 10,
    },
    {
        condition:'AND',
        id: 'followers_count', 
        operator: 'GTE' 
        value: 150,
    } 
  ]
```

The array should return the object if it matches conditions in bitwise operator's execution order. Please let me know what will be the optimized code for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter each item using an `every` call on the `conditions`. Just `switch` on the `operator` and use `item[id]` to compare against the `value`.

I changed the second item to the following so that it adhears to the constraints:

```js
{
  name: 'Bob Perren',
  screen_name: 'hperren1d',
  followers_count: 300,
  following_count: 5,
  location: 'Mexico',
  verified: true,
}
```

```js
const filterWithConditions = (arr, conditions) =>
  arr.filter(item => conditions.every(({ id, operator, value }) => {
    switch (operator) {
      case 'CONTAINS' : return item[id].indexOf(value) > -1;
      case 'GTE'      : return item[id] >= value;
      case 'LTE'      : return item[id] <= value;
      default         : return false;
    }
  }));

const arrayToFilter = [{
  name: 'Arlin Schistl',
  screen_name: 'aschistl1c',
  followers_count: 101,
  following_count: 657,
  location: 'Indonesia',
  verified: true,
}, {
  name: 'Bob Perren',
  screen_name: 'hperren1d',
  followers_count: 300,
  following_count: 5,
  location: 'Mexico',
  verified: true,
}]

const conditions = [
  { id: 'name'            , operator: 'CONTAINS' ,  value: 'Bob' },
  { id: 'followers_count' , operator: 'GTE'      ,  value: 200   },
  { id: 'following_count' , operator: 'LTE'      ,  value: 10    }
];

const filtered = filterWithConditions(arrayToFilter, conditions);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively, you could use a object (map) lookup instead of a `switch`.

```js
const operators = {
  CONTAINS : (a, b) => a.indexOf(b) > -1,
  GTE      : (a, b) => a >= b,
  LTE      : (a, b) => a <= b
}

const filterWithConditions = (arr, conditions) =>
  arr.filter(item => conditions.every(({ id, operator, value }) =>
    operators[operator](item[id], value)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the sol. Sorry I also need to filter the array if any of the condition is true, can u change the code for that accordingly, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a map from your string to the operator, and then just loop over your array:

```
const operators = {
   "CONTAINS" : (...) => {...}
   "GTE" : (...) => {...}
   "LTE" : (...) => {...}
}
let res = arrayToFilter.filter( el => {
   return conditions.every( cond => operators(el[id]))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Berto. By the way I have updated my question as in previous one it doesn't have a clear view, can u let me know the optimized way of achieving that. Thanks!